# Ember Emberfire Query

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, emberfire

I'm new to Ember, and have been impressed so far by how succinct everything is. Though querying data with EmberFire seems a little odd. For instance, in a component's js I can find a record with :

```
store.query('user', { orderBy: 'email', equalTo: email }).then((response) => {
  // expect response to be an object, or an array of objects
  // but its actually a class, and needs the following to return data      
  var user = response.get('content')[0]._data;

  // now able to access properties as originally expected
  console.log(user.email);
});
```

While the above works, it doesn't feel very elegant. Am I missing something? As far as I can see the documentation stops at explaining the query, so any help as to the proper way of accessing a model's properties would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`store.query` returns a promise that resolves to a [AdapterPopulatedRecordArray](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.AdapterPopulatedRecordArray.html). So yes, it should be returning a class.

If you're expecting only 1 record to be returned, then you should use `queryRecord`.

```
store.queryRecord('user', { orderBy: 'email', equalTo: email }).then((user) => {
  // now able to access properties as expected
  console.log(user.get('email'));
});
```

If you're expecting more than 1 record, keep using `query` and you'll be able to loop through the user results that are returned.

Comment: "You tried to make a query but your adapter does not implement `queryRecord`", name: "Error"…}description: undefinedfileName: undefinedlineNumber: undefinedmessage: "Assertion Failed: You tried to make a query but your adapter does not implement `queryRecord`"name:

Comment: What version of ember and adapter are you using?

Comment: "emberfire": "2.0.4"
ember-cli: 2.8.0
node: 4.0.0

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it looks like the ember fire adapter does not adhere to the ember data api, and so it does not implement `queryRecord`. https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/405

Answer (score 0):

This problem has existed for a while and it's because `EmberFire` was deprecated before anybody wrote an elegant way to query this way.

[This add-on](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-emberfire-find-query) solves the problem, and will let you query pretty much any way you can imagine with the `filterCustom` method.